# Handlebars helper problem unsolvable in Node.js

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I have this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'SafeString' of null
App.js:

```
//MIDDLEWARE PER HANDLEBARS
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({
defaultLayout: 'main',    
helpers: require('./helpers/handlebars').helpers, //esternal container
}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
```

helpers/handlebars:

```
var register = function(Handlebars) {
  var helpers = {   
    totaleMacrofase: function(macrofase, value){
      if (macrofase == "TOTALE")
      {
        let result = "<strong>" + value + "</strong>";
         return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);    
      }
      else{
        return value;
      }    
    }
  };

  if (Handlebars && typeof Handlebars.registerHelper === "function") {
    // register helpers
    for (var prop in helpers) {     
        Handlebars.registerHelper(prop, helpers[prop]);
    }
  } else {  
      // just return helpers object if we can't register helpers here
      return helpers;
  }

};

module.exports.register = register;
module.exports.helpers = register(null);
```

there is no guide to solve the problem, any suggestion is welcome, thanks

Comment: I'm confused. What is the `Handlebars` parameter in the `register` function supposed to be when you call `register(null)`?

Comment: I found this example on stackoverflow, but I didn't understand where the error might be, thank you